# Calling a specific method on a certain time

Tags: web

I am currently working on a web application and I want to schedule a method that runs every day at 6 AM. Basically, if the clock ticks at 6 AM, this method will run. I have seen some answers on the Internet but none of these are scheduled at a fixed time of the day but rather timed after the app is ran.

I also have an alternative solution which is to check every minute if the time is 6 AM, and if so, I'll run the code. But is there other better answer than this?

Thank you!

Comment: How about a cron job? Is it a server side or a client side event that needs to be triggered at a specific time?

Comment: @show-me-the-code Server side. I'll check out cron job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, you could do it with a cron job.

On Linux follow these steps:

`crontab -e`

Here's an example of how to make a request to the google.com at 6AM (UTC)

```bash
# Each day at 6th hour (6 AM depending on your time zone settings, or UTC)
0 6 * * * curl -I http://google.com

:wq # save changes and quit
:q # to quit
:q! # to quit without saving changes
```

See more about Cron [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Or use a [visual crontab entry creator](http://www.corntab.com/pages/crontab-gui) if that is helpful. If you need a solution for Windows machine, you could also use a Windows scheduler to trigger events similar to cron.

Answer (score 1):

Cron job would be a good way of doing it. However, for some reason if you can not schedule a cron job and need your own scheduler and your environment is **Java based** then you could use the [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). It is a java based job scheduler like cron. It's usage is pretty simple.